# Connect to MongoDb that is running in a Docker Container that is running inside a server

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, docker

I am trying to connect to MongoDb that is running inside a docker container. This docker Container is running inside a server, let us say (192.158.8.02). How to i write a connection string to connect to the MongoDb.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(“mongodb://mongo:27017/”)
```

here mongo is container name

how to solve this?

Comment: On the server where MongoDb docker container is running, map host port(say 37017) to port (27017) on Mongo container. Then use server host ip/name say client=MongoClient("mongodb://192.158.8.2:37017").